# требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен python

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

Всем привет, при попытке выполнить свой код cmd выдёт вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
import socket, time

host = "31.128.146.190"
port = 9090

clients = []

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))

quit = False
print("[ Server Started ]", host)

while not quit:
try:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)

    if addr not in clients:
        clients.append(addr)

    itsatime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S", time.localtime())

    print("["+addr[0]+"]=["+str(addr[1])+"]=["+itsatime+"]/",end="")
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))

    for client in clients:
        if addr != client:
            s.sendto(data,client)
except: 
    print("\n[ Server Stopped ]")
    quit = True

s.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
s.bind((host,port))
```

попробуй сделать

```js
s.bind(("",port))
```

Comment: Не работает....

Comment: s.bind(("localhost",port)) ||| если вы пытаетесь подрубиться из вне, то не забудьте открыть порт `sudo ufw allow 9090`

Comment: Я на винде :(((

Comment: Тогда гугл в помощь в таком порядке: 1) как проверить открытые порты windows 2) открыть порт в windows. Плохо помню но там вроде как- через брандмауер настраивается